# Best way to store one variable in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an interesting problem where I have a job processing architecture that has a limit on how many jobs can be processed at once. When another job is about to start, it needs to check how many jobs are being processed, and if it is at the threshold, add the job to a queue.

What has stumped me is the best way to implement a "counter" that tracks the number of jobs running at once? This counter needs to be accessed and incremented up and down from different lambda functions.

My first thought was a CloudWatch custom high latency metric, but 1 second is not quick enough, as the system breaks if too many jobs are submitted. Additionally, I'm not sure if the metric can be incremented up or down only through code. The only thing I can think of now is an entire separate DB or EC2 instance, but that seems like complete overkill for just ONE number. We are not using a DB for data storage, it is in another cloud platform, only S3.

Any suggestions on what to do next? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Take a look at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/controlling-concurrency-in-distributed-systems-using-aws-step-functions/ - you're looking for a counting semaphore.

Comment: @stdunbar this is absolutely what I was looking for, really appreciate the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DynamoDB table to hold your counter as a document. However, keep in mind that some operations in DynamoDB could lead to race conditions, so you might want to “lock” your table.

Depending on your load, this could potentially be free, given the Free Tier.